# Limiting input in datepicker from angular bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I would like to block and format input for my datepicker.
The problem is my blocking input directive is not working for datepicker when it's working for other fields.
That's my code for datepicker:

```
      <p class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="medicalExaminationDate"
               name="medicalExaminationDate" class="form-control" datepicker-localdate date-input
               uib-datepicker-popup="{{user.format}}"
               ng-model="user.parent.data3" is-open="user.popup3.opened"
               datepicker-options="user.dateOptions" ng-required="true"
               close-text="Zamknij"
               clear-text="Wyczyść"
               current-text="Dzisiaj"

               required
               placeholder="data"/>

      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                ng-click="user.open3()">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
      </span>
      </p>
```

And in controller:

```
 //datepicker
  vm.parent = {data1: '',data2:'', data3:''};
  vm.formats = ['yyyy-MM-dd'];
  vm.format = vm.formats[0];
  //vm.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];
  vm.popup1 = {
    opened: false
  };
  vm.popup2 = {
    opened: false
  };
 vm.popup3 = {
   opened: false
 };
 vm.dateOptions = {
  dateDisabled: disabled,
  formatYear: 'yyyy',
  maxDate: new Date(2050, 12, 31),
  minDate: new Date(1950,1,1),
  startingDay: 1
 };
  vm.setDate = setDate;
  function setDate(year, month, day) {
   vm.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
 }
 vm.open1 = open1;
 vm.open2 = open2;
 vm.open3 = open3;


 function open1() {
   vm.popup1.opened = true;
 }
 function open2() {
   vm.popup2.opened = true;
 }
 function open3() {
   vm.popup3.opened = true;
 }
 // Disable weekend selection
 function disabled(data) {
  var date = data.date,
    mode = data.mode;
  return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
 }
```

Now, what I want to do is block input after 8 characters and format it to 'XXXX-XX-XX'.
The directive I'm using to block input in other fields, that is not working at all for datepicker (I can add as many characters to input as I want, It's not blocking it, when in normal input fields its working great):

```
   .directive('myMaxlength', ['$compile', '$log', function($compile, $log) {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      attrs.$set("ngTrim", "false");
      var maxlength = parseInt(attrs.myMaxlength, 10);
      ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
        $log.info("In parser function value = [" + value + "].");
        if (value.length > maxlength)
        {
          $log.info("The value [" + value + "] is too long!");
          value = value.substr(0, maxlength);
          ctrl.$setViewValue(value);
          ctrl.$render();
          $log.info("The value is now truncated as [" + value + "].");
        }
        return value;
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

And the second one for formating with filter included, taht is somewaht working but not as I want it to (below filter code I added what is wrong):

```
 .directive('dateInput', function($filter, $browser) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      var listener = function () {
        var value = $element.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        $element.val($filter('dateFormat')(value, false));

      };


      // This runs when the model gets updated on the scope directly and keeps our view in sync
      ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
        $element.val($filter('dateFormat')(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue, false));
      };

      $element.bind('change', listener);
      $element.bind('keydown', function (event) {
        var key = event.keyCode;
        // If the keys include the CTRL, SHIFT, ALT, or META keys, or the arrow keys, do nothing.
        // This lets us support copy and paste too
        if (key == 91 || (15 < key && key < 19) || (37 <= key && key <= 40)) {
          return;
        }
        $browser.defer(listener); // Have to do this or changes don't get picked up properly

      });

      $element.bind('paste cut', function () {
        $browser.defer(listener);
      });
    }

  }
})
```

With filter:

```
  .filter('dateFormat', function () {
  return function (dateFormat) {
    console.log(dateFormat);
    if (!dateFormat) { return ''; }

    var value = dateFormat.toString().trim().replace(/^\+/, '');
    //value= value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').slice(0,8);
    if (value.match(/[^0-9]/)) {
      return dateFormat;
    }


    var year, month, day;

    switch (value.length) {
      case 1:
      case 2:
      case 3:
        year = value;
        break;

      default:
        year = value.slice(0, 4);
        month = value.slice(4, 6);
        day = value.slice(6, 10);
    }

    return (year + "-" + month + "-" + day).trim();


  };
});
```

With this in my filter:

```
  //value= value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').slice(0,8);
```

I can limit input to 8 characters but form is losing validity If i try to add something after 8th character, for example:
I have valid 1990-11-11, then I'm clicking 7. 7 is not added to input bit input lost validity and I need to delete last character in input ('1') and add it again to get valid input.
Why is that and what I can do to repair it?

Comment: I found a solution in UI-mask module from https://angular-ui.github.io/.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in ui-mask module from angular-ui.github.io.

Comment: So what was the solution??